# Does Ubuntu provide patched version of openssl for 12.10?

Tags: openssl

12.10 is right at end of life in April 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, here's the [changelog](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.0.1c-3ubuntu2.7/changelog) for the openssl package in 12.10 showing the Heartbleed fix released on April 7.

Comment: Yes, I see I got it, I forgot to restart Apache. Thanks.